# Unable to download terraform modules from azure repo (Private repo)

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure, azure-repos

My terraform-modules repo location is like this:

```
https://teamabc.visualstudio.com/dummyproject/_git/terraform-modules?path=%2Fcompute&version=GBmaster
```

I have three directories/modules at root level, namely compute, resourcegroup and sqlserver.
However, when I run terraform init. terraform is unable to download the required modules.

**main.tf**

```
module "app_vms" {
  source                = "https://teamabc.visualstudio.com/dummyproject/_git/terraform-modules?path=%2Fcompute&version=GBmaster"
  rg_name               = var.resource_group_name
  location              = module.resource_group.external_rg_location
  vnet_name             = var.virtual_network_name
  subnet_name           = var.sql_subnet_name
  app_nsg               = var.application_nsg
  vm_count              = var.count_vm
  base_hostname         = var.app_host_basename
  sto_acc_suffix        = var.storage_account_suffix
  vm_size               = var.virtual_machine_size
  vm_publisher          = var.virtual_machine_image_publisher
  vm_offer              = var.virtual_machine_image_offer
  vm_sku                = var.virtual_machine_image_sku
  vm_img_version        = var.virtual_machine_image_version
  username              = var.username
  password              = var.password
  allowed_source_ips    = var.ip_list
}

module "resource_group" {
  source                = "https://teamabc.visualstudio.com/dummyproject/_git/terraform-modules?path=%2Fresourcegroup&version=GBmaster"
  rg_name               = "test_rg"
}

module "azure_paas_sqlserver" {
  source                = "https://teamabc.visualstudio.com/dummyproject/_git/terraform-modules?path=%2Fsqlserver&version=GBmaster"  
}
```

It gives me a series of errors like below:(sample only give not all the errors as they are same)

```
Error: Failed to download module

Could not download module "sql_vms" (main.tf:1) source code from
"https://teamabc.visualstudio.com/dummpproject/_git/terraform-modules?path=%2Fcompute&version=GBmaster":
error downloading
'https://teamabc.visualstudio.com/dummyproject/_git/terraform-modules?path=%2Fcompute&version=GBmaster':
no source URL was returned


Error: Failed to download module

Could not download module "sql_vms" (main.tf:1) source code from
"https://teamabc.visualstudio.com/dummyproject/_git/terraform-modules?path=%2Fcompute&version=GBmaster":
error downloading
'https://teamabc.visualstudio.com/dummyproject/_git/terraform-modules?path=%2Fcompute&version=GBmaster':
no source URL was returned
```

I tried to remove **https://** part but no luck. The repo does require username and password to login.

Wondering if I should be making a public repo in github? but push within the organization is to use Azure Repos.

---

Post First comment

---

Thanks for the lead, I did tried but still no charm.

My source url now looks like below

```
  source                = "git::https://teamabc:lfithww4xpp4eksvoimgzkpi3ugu6xvrkf26mfq3jth3642jgyoa@visualstudio.com/dummyproject/_git/terraform-modules?path=%2Fcompute&version=GBmaster"
```

I get error below:

```
Error: Failed to download module

Could not download module "sql_vms" (main.tf:1) source code from
"git::https://teamabc:lfithww4xpp4eksvoimgzkpi3ugu6xvrkf26mfq3jth3642jgyoa@visualstudio.com/dummyproject/_git/terraform-modules?path=%2Fcompute&version=GBmaster":
error downloading
'https://teamabc:lfithww4xpp4eksvoimgzkpi3ugu6xvrkf26mfq3jth3642jgyoa@visualstudio.com/dummyproject/_git/terraform-modules?path=%2Fcompute&version=GBmaster':
/usr/bin/git exited with 128: Cloning into '.terraform/modules/sql_vms'...
fatal: repository
'https://teamabc:lfithww4xpp4eksvoimgzkpi3ugu6xvrkf26mfq3jth3642jgyoa@visualstudio.com/dummyproject/_git/terraform-modules?path=%2Fcompute&version=GBmaster/'
not found
```

Here:

**teamabc.visuastudio.com** is the parent azure devops url

**dummyproject** is the **project name**

**After Charles Response**

```
Error: Failed to download module

Could not download module "sql_vms" (main.tf:1) source code from
"git::https://teamabc:lfithww4xpp4eksvoimgzkpi3ugu6xvrkf26mfq3jth3642jgyoa@visualstudio.com/dummyproject/_git/terraform-modules?path=%2Fcompute&version=GBmaster.git":
error downloading
'https://teamabc:lfithww4xpp4eksvoimgzkpi3ugu6xvrkf26mfq3jth3642jgyoa@visualstudio.com/dummyproject/_git/terraform-modules?path=%2Fcompute&version=GBmaster.git':
/usr/bin/git exited with 128: Cloning into '.terraform/modules/sql_vms'...
fatal: repository
'https://teamabc:lfithww4xpp4eksvoimgzkpi3ugu6xvrkf26mfq3jth3642jgyoa@visualstudio.com/dummyproject/_git/terraform-modules?path=%2Fcompute&version=GBmaster.git/'
not found
```

Comment: Did you try https://stackoverflow.com/a/57557181/220935?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can take a look at [Generic Git Repository](https://www.terraform.io/docs/modules/sources.html#generic-git-repository), the URL should be a Git URL. And finally, it should like this:

```
source                = "git::https://teamabc:lfithww4xpp4eksvoimgzkpi3ugu6xvrkf26mfq3jth3642jgyoa@visualstudio.com/dummyproject/_git/terraform-modules?path=%2Fcompute&version=GBmaster.git"
```

Or you can select a branch from your Git Repository like this:

```
source                = "git::https://teamabc:lfithww4xpp4eksvoimgzkpi3ugu6xvrkf26mfq3jth3642jgyoa@visualstudio.com/dummyproject/_git/terraform-modules?path=%2Fcompute&version=GBmaster.git?ref=<branch>"
```

Finally, got it working by below command:

```
git::https://<PAT TOKEN>@<Azure DevOps URL>/DefaultCollection/<PROJECT NAME>/_git/<REPO NAME>//<sub directory>
```

Comment: Sir, as you see in my update. I tried the url ending with .git. Still not  working. Error below.

Comment: Sir, I have added the log at the bottom part of the question. Thank you.

Comment: @learner I cannot access the web page, only get the 404 error. How can I access the page which you store the module?

Comment: Finally got it working by below
git::https://,PAT TOKEN>@<Azure DevOps URL>/DefaultCollection/<PROJECT NAME>/_git/terraform-modules//resourcegroup

Comment: Finally got it working by below
git::https://<PAT TOKEN>@<Azure DevOps URL>/DefaultCollection/<PROJECT NAME>/_git/<REPO NAME>//<sub directory>

Comment: Apologies for the delay. Was sick. I used the URl which I learnt from public forums. Glad to see it is working now.

Comment: Question is more around for source url on local VM not on Azure Pipelines agent. Solution does work on Azure Pipelines as well BUT the PAT TOKEN is hard coded which is not a great idea.

Comment: Is there a way to get this working without hardcoding the PAT token?