# Is it possible to use service principal to access git repository on azure?

Tags: git, azure

I have a git repository hosted on Microsoft Azure repos within an organization.

I want to be able to automatically "git pull" code from a service that is hosted outside of Azure.

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/auth-overview?view=azure-devops) only mentions git authentication with Personal Access Token or with a private SSH key.

I don't want to use Personal Access Token since other developers of the service could get access to it.

Is it possible to use service principal instead to pull the code from the Azure repository?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This may have been correct as of 2021 but in 2023 we have the absolute *magic* that is [OAuth tokens for AAD identities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/account?view=azure-cli-latest#az-account-get-access-token).

One important caveat - this only works for *AAD-backed Azure DevOps*.

In essence to clone an Azure Repository using **only a service principal** we need to follow the below steps

1. Create a [Service Principal in the Azure Portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-create-service-principal-portal). Note that you can use either client secret or certificate authentication here as you'll use the credentials later on in the Azure CLI
2. Add the Service Principal to your Azure Devops organisation and assign it permissions on the Azure Repositories you care about, just as you would any other user. [This excellent Microsoft page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/azure/devops/integrate/get-started/authentication/service-principal-managed-identity?view=azure-devops#configure-managed-identities-and-service-principals) contains a video on how to do this. Effectively you can now see Service Principals in the list of users and they function identically to any other "user account".
3. Use the following code to authenticate using either a client secret (1) or client certificate (2)

> az login --service-principal --allow-no-subscriptions --username
> [YOUR_APP_ID] --password [YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET] --tenant [YOUR_TENANT_ID]

> az login --service-principal --allow-no-subscriptions --username [YOUR_APP_ID] --password [PATH_TO_YOUR_PEM_FILE] --tenant [YOUR_TENANT_ID]

4. The magic. Obtain an OAuth token using the following command:

> az account get-access-token --scope "499b84ac-1321-427f-aa17-267ca6975798/.default"

Note that the scope here is *hard coded* as it's a [fixed value used by Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/tokens/?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0&tabs=powershell#personal-access-tokens-pats)

5. This will return a JSON object similar to the below (which is a classic OAuth access token structure):

> {
> "accessToken": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1...",
> "expiresOn": "2023-06-13 22:15:28.000000",
> "subscription": "[YOUR SUBSCRIPTION]",
> "tenant": "[YOUR TENANT]",
> "tokenType": "Bearer"
> }

6. The slam dunk. Use this token as your **password** in the git clone URL (example below):

> git clone https://[ACCESS_TOKEN]@dev.azure.com/[YOUR_ORG]/[YOUR_PROJECT]/_git/[YOUR_REPOSITORY]

This will, incredibly, allow you to clone a repository purely using a service principal. I can barely believe I'm writing this, but welcome to the future.

**Edit** Another SO user requested a pure cURL answer to this which is documented in a [different answer I provided here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76519055/1196415)

Comment: Posting comment from Malhar (he doesn't have enough rep):
The token will expire after 3599 sec. and git will persist the first token, after the first token has expired, it becomes tricky to do the same process over and over. can git-credential-manager do this automatically for us ?

Comment: What about multi-tenancy? Can I create an App in Tenant_A, then in Tenant_B consent this app, and add the service principal as a new user in the DevOps Organization? Then, can I programmatically access some project/repo from Tenant_B using app credentials from Tenant_A?

Comment: @OleksiyKachynskyy I have not tried this but I see no reason technically why it would not work. The Enterprise Application will exist in Tenant_B, and therefore the service principal should also exist there. The litmus test is whether the service principal appears in the user list for your Azure Devops organization. If it does, any rights you assign that will be available programatically as above. Please report back!

Comment: Thanks for the reply! But it does not work, even if I see the service principal after consenting the app. I have described my issue in depth here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77564386/azure-devops-repos-rest-api-access-using-service-principal-multi-tenant-app

Comment: I can't get this to work. For some reason. At the second step, I don't see the service Principal in Azure DevOps, it just doesn't show up. Is there something specific to configure for this to happen?
Other than that, I can `az login` using the service principal credentials, but access to DevOps using the token return a 401

Comment: @Nooodles I've done this several times now without issue, so I suspect something else is happening.  Are you an AAD (now Entra ID) administrator? Are you an Azure DevOps organisation admin? Do you see the service principal in the organisation list when you search/add users? Are there policies you can think of that might be limiting you?

Comment: @Nooodles worst case consider opening a new question with all the background details of your situation and link to this one, I'm sure we can figure it out.

Comment: @JamesG well, only later I realized that the AAD subscription where I created the service principal is not the one backing the DevOps organization...
So I guess I'll have to find a different way (I can't create app registrations in the sub backing the DevOps org).

Comment: I just ran into a problem with the Access Level that is assigned to the SP. By default in our org this is "Stakeholder". I needed to change the Access Level to "Basic" to access the repos API with the token.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the way to programmatically access git repository hosted on Azure is to create a service account on Azure and issue Personal Access Token for this account.

Azure doesn't provide the ability to issue a service principle to access git repositories.