# Clone git with workload/ federated identity

Tags: git, azure, azure-devops, federated-identity, workload-identity

I currently use a service connection of type `Azure Repos/Team Foundation Server service connection`. Currently this uses a PAT which I wish to eliminate.

My goal is a clone a git repository hosted on an Azuredevops completely different tenant (see below for code)

Is there a way to replace `Azure Repos/Team Foundation Server service connection` with Federated identity so that a clone can be done across tenants? On a [similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76465031/azure-devops-pipeline-git-clone-with-service-principal/76519055?noredirect=1#comment135007673_76519055), we had figured out how to do this with bash, service principal and password, but now that workload identity is released it will be good to eliminate the `client_secret` completely.

**Current Code**

```
resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: iac
    type: git
    name: project/iac
    ref: "master"
    endpoint: xxx_git
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is not yet possible. Federated identity is so far supported only for `Azure Resource Manager` service connection and followign built-in tasks

> AzureAppServiceManage, AzureAppServiceSettings, AzureCLI, AzureCloudPowerShellDeployment, AzureContainerApps, AzureFunctionAppContainer, AzureFunctionApp, AzureKeyVault, AzureMonitor, AzureMysqlDeployment, AzurePolicy, AzurePowerShell, AzureResourceGroupDeployment, AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment, AzureRmWebAppDeployment, AzureSpringCloud, AzureVmssDeployment, AzureWebAppContainer, AzureWebApp, DockerCompose, Docker, HelmDeploy, InvokeRestApi, JavaToolInstaller, JenkinsDownloadArtifacts, Kubernetes.

Info about you can find [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/public-preview-of-workload-identity-federation-for-azure-pipelines/#built-in-pipeline-tasks).

We can expect to have this extended in the future but now this is the limitation.

Comment: Would it be possible to use servicing connection using service principal and ClientSecret instead ? Until Microsoft support GIT?