# Git Clone alternatives to PAT token

Tags: git, azure, azure-devops, active-directory, azure-service-principal

I have a case where where I need to clone git repos across multiple separate orginisations. Currently I use `Azure Repos/Team Foundation Server` with a PAT token.

I would like to eliminate PAT tokens for good and prefer to use another auth method which can be renewed by other team members. I see few ways of achieving this

1. Use federated identity -> Ideal situation but think this is not supported by Microsoft yet
2. Create an App Registration and use a `ClientID` & `ClientSecret` and store in a ServiceConnection (ideal since it does not require code changes)
3. Create a App Registration and use a `ClientID` & `ClientSecret` and setup as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76465031/azure-devops-pipeline-git-clone-with-service-principal)
4. Use ARM to somehow connect

Is there a way to accomplish the above using (1) or (2). I am sure (3) will work but this will require me to create quite abit bash code and is a little "messy"

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

According to [the release note](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/2023/sprint-227-update#workload-identity-federation-in-azure-pipelines-public-preview), Workload identity federation can be used in Azure Pipelines now (public preview)  .

We create a new Azure service connection using workload identity federation. You can refer [this blog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/public-preview-of-workload-identity-federation-for-azure-pipelines/) for more details.

[image]

Comment: But is GIT supported? Can you please elaborate on how to do a git clone with this method?